# Insert Item Template in Asp.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

What I want is How to have a Insert Item Template in Asp.NET.
Like in a Add User Page.I Get Automatically All the Items and the Text Boxes After That.

And the Create User Button in the end.

The same i Want .All Items along with the Text Boxes And the Insert Button At the End.And the Items should be Inserted into the Database.

What I Want is to permanently Display the Insert Item Page.

For Ex:- In Case of Students :

FisrtName:-----------
MiddleName:----------
LastName:------------

Without Any Button Been Clicked.
Like a AddStudent Page or Create Student Page.

I Think You Got My Point

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is it the GridView? Or FormView?

Comment: If it's a FormView, you could call `FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)` before you `DataBind` it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a FormView as you've commented, you should call [FormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.changemode.aspx):

```
Me.FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert)
Me.FormView1.DataBind()
```